# What happens in Wolsung when you can't take more scars?

Tags: wolsung

In Wolsung, when a PC loses conflicts, they lose attribute points. Once they reach 0, they gain a scar.

A scar has a dual effect: it provides a bonus to one attribute and negatively affects another. However, a single attribute can only be affected by one scar.

Thus there's a maximum number of scars a PC can take in total, before they run out of "space" to apply new scars.

A PC in Wolsung, aside from playing "va banque", is invincible - they can be taken out of a fight, but never killed. So what happens should a PC ever reach the point of having so many scars, that they can't get a new one in?

Answer (score 1):

From a medical perspective, there could be a situation where a new scar could form over an old scar or scars.  Perhaps if a new scar forms, the PC has to discard one or more old scars, and their associated bonuses, because they are essentially destroyed and incorporated into a new scar tissue association.

Comment: Be mindful that scars need not be physical. They can be caused by being ridiculed by an opponent in an important debate (a PC loses a discussion conflict). In these cases "scars" are mental.